# Multithreading RNG from Boost.Random

Tags: c++, boost, random, openmp

I am trying to include multithreading into my program, which is shown at the end of the thread. I am having some difficulties with the part regarding the RNG, which I use `boost/random` for. I am using OpenMP for the multithreading. I can understand that the variate generator of Boost does not support safe multithreading, but I am trying hard to find a way out of this, having had no luck so far. Note that the function `norm` is used later in my program, but this time on a single thread. I'm mentioning this, since it may rule out some solutions (or maybe not)..

**My own approach so far**: I have tried safe-guarding by using `#pragma omp critical` before generating the number, but in that case multithreading does not yield an increase in computation speed (I have compared by timing...)

I have deliberately posted the simplest version of my problem, so solutions can be illustrated, if desired. Even though I am using OpenMP, I am also willing to switch to Boost.Thread, if it is easier to achieve there such that I get see some progress.

**EDIT** I have read multiple places that creating an instance of the RNG for each thread is one option, but I would be very happy to see, how this can be done in practice.

Thanks for participating in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::mt19937 engine(static_cast<unsigned int>(0));
    boost::normal_distribution<double> dis(0.0, 1.0);
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, boost::normal_distribution<double> > norm(engine, dis);

    unsigned long long app=0;
    unsigned long long i;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) reduction(+:app)
    for(i=0; i<1234567890; i++)
    {
        double temp = norm();
        if(temp < 0.5) app++;
    }
    cout << app << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So generating the variates is the bottleneck in your computation?  You need each thread to use its own RNG.

Comment: @tmyklebu thanks for your interest. do you have an example of how to do this, in the setting of my simple example in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You could grab a mutex or something before generating the variate and release it afterward, like this:

```
std::mutex mu;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0;i<123456789;i++) {
  double temp;
  { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    temp = norm();
  }
  if (temp < 0.5) app++;
}
```

A more sensible option would be to have one RNG for each thread.  I'm sure this is possible with OpenMP, but I don't know how.

Comment: Such mutex will make parallelism useless. It will be even worse than ordinary loop due to high contention.

Comment: @Greg: Depends on how much time is spent in the RNG and how much is spent doing work with the random numbers.  If all you're doing is an 'if' and a conditional increment, you're absolutely right.  But if you're doing something that's considerably more expensive, this'll work.

Comment: You're right, I assumed that generating the variates is much more expensive.